# which priority is higher when setting ENV in PM2

Tags: pm2

`PORT=8000 pm2 start app.config.js`
in app.config.js, the PORT is set to 8080, then which Port will PM2 start on?
I thought 8000, but it started on 8080, Could anyone explain why?

explain the which priority is higher for command line and the configuration file

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I found the answer.
PM2 will inject environment in this order when starting a new process :

1. First the PM2 CLI will use its environment so the current environment of your shell will be injected.
2. PM2 will then inject the environment that you can configure with the ecosystem file

https://pm2.keymetrics.io/docs/usage/environment/